# "Preview in Window" does not work in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

In Rstudio, how can I see my plots in "Preview in Window" instead of "Preview in Viewer Pane" ? I already have changed setting as:

```
 tools---global optinos---R Markdown----show output preview in window
```

But, still it does not work.

Comment: Try dev.new(). you might need to do it twice as the first one opens in the Viewer pane. You can use windows() if you are using a windows machine

Comment: apparently there is a argument to the Rstudio version of dev.new() to not use the viewer pane: dev.new(noRStudioGD = TRUE)

Comment: Actually, I tried dev.new() and windows() (since i am working in windows) commands, both are not working. It still shows plot in "Viewer Pane" and open an empty "R Graphics :Device 5(ACTIVE)"

Comment: dev.new() and windows() do not change where a plot is shown, they open a new empty graphics window, then the next plot functions will effect that window/device

Comment: That is, you should call windows(), prior to calling your plot function.

Comment: Now, I do like that in Conosle: windows();plot(data$x, data$y) and I see plot in different winodw "R Graphics Device 4 (ACTIVE)" . But, it means everytime I need to write windows() command before my plot? there is no other ways, that no need to write every time this command.  I also have this problem when  run a shiny app chunk, results are in "Viewer pnae" that I prefer to be poped up in new window

Comment: You can use options(device = windows) at the start of your script, this will make the windows the default for opening as a new device. (It still won't open a new device for each plot, only the first plot then overwrite).